# Cómo recorrer un objeto reactivo en vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue3, programación-reactiva, pinia

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Vue3 y me surge una duda que no soy capaz de solucionar.
La idea es que al renderizar la página en cuestión, mostrará una lista de documentación, la cual obtengo haciendo un fetch. Cada uno de los documentos aparecerán como en una lista y cada uno tendrá su propio botón de eliminar. Al pulsar el botón de eliminar hago un DELETE a la api y este se elimina.
Para poner en contexto, estoy usando el store de Pinia y estoy declarando lo siguiente:
Obtención de la lista de documentos:

```
async getProjectDocumentation(jwt, projectId){
      try{
        const uri = `${this.BASE_URL}/projects/${projectId}?populate[documentations][populate][0]=uploaded_document`
        const rawResponse = await fetch (uri, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`
          }
        })
                const res = await rawResponse.json()
                if (res){
                    this.docuList =  res.data.attributes.documentations // this.docuList está declarado como reactivo
                }else{
                    return false
                }

                } catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
```

en el componente estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="doc in docList.data" :key="doc.id">
        {{ doc }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
let docList = reactive([])

//al montar el componente hago una llamada getProjectDocumentation y seguidamente obtengo 
//la docuList del store (la cual es reactiva) y la almaceno en docList (la cual es reactiva también)

onMounted(async () => {
  projectId.value = route.params.id
  await docStore.getProjectDocumentation(jwt, projectId.value)
    docList = docStore.docuList
    console.log(docList.data) // aquí obtengo el objeto con el array
})
</setup>
```

El array que obtengo:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 42,
      "attributes": {
        "doc_name": "asg",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-11T13:17:51.941Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-11T13:17:53.067Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-09-11T13:17:53.065Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 43,
      "attributes": {
        "doc_name": "doc1",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-11T14:47:03.092Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-11T14:47:05.928Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-09-11T14:47:05.925Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Pero a pesar de estar recibiendo el objeto y aparentemente lo estoy guardando en docList soy incapaz de renderizar nada. (Esto mismo ejercicio lo había hecho con ref y si que lo estaba renderizando, pero no obtenía la reactividad).
Después de todo el día rompiéndome la cabeza no me queda más que pediros ayuda...
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tengo varias dudas de lo que estas haciendo... no deberias usar reactive para nada... si estas usando pinia, los objetos dentro de pinia ya son reactivos... no deberias declarar el objeto afuera tambien...

Comment: Donde definiste el store dentro de tu componente?

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @gbianchi. El código que he pasado tan solo es un fragmento, está todo declarado.. El caso es que haciendo el console.log(docList.data) recibo el objeto correctamente, pero no consigo renderizarlo en el v-for..

Comment: En ese caso, te alcanza con hacer un for sobre el objeto declarado dentro del store. Muestras como tienes esa parte del store?